What is the reason for the curly braces underlined in red?
enter image description hereI was following a tutorial of firebase, in which he was trying to display the data in firebase by using streambuilder. I followed everything as he said, but somehow there is a red line error below my curly brace.
When i hover over it, it reads : The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type. (Documentation)  Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.
enter image description here

It means you aren't returning a Widget in all possible branches.

As it says: 'You must return something'. For instance if ConnectionState is active, you are returning but you forget to return a widget if it is not.. Again, you forget to return a widget if  the inner if is not true.

You do not have a return statement in your else branch:
else {
  print('...');
}

this does not return anything

You could add a “return Placeholder();” or “return SizedBox();” below the print and it should work.
